# Why favicon is it broken when I add it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, favicon, spring-webflow

I've imported the favicon with the classic method, (the context is a springboot application +thymeleaf with spring webflow),    `<link href="./static/myFolder/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>`
But it's broken and size is 0x0 (browser view). I tried to import another but it is not displayed.

[image: break favicon]

Comment: `"static/myFolder/img/favicon.ico"` or `"/static/myFolder/img/favicon.ico"` or ...

Comment: How I know by default the content of static folder exposed to application context root so you don't need word static in path to favicon.

Answer (score 0):

Put the favicon file into the folder

```
/resources/static/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to override the default favicon of a Spring Boot application is to place the new favicon in the resources directory:
( Make sure your icon is an .ico type and not a PNG|JPG|GIF ...)

**Note** : You don't need to add a link tag with an src to your HTML file, Spring will automatically detect and add it, so Just remove this .

```
<link href="./static/myFolder/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
```

And put your icon in this location :

```
src/main/resources/favicon.ico
```

Clear Cache of you browser before test ✅.

You can have a custom location but you should add some congifs : here is a helpful link : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon